# Why am I getting an error using Html.RenderAction. CS0103: The name 'Html' does not exist in the current context

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I am working with this book from Apress.
Pro ASP.NET MVC 2 Framework, Second Edition, Updated.
I am in chapter 5  SportsStore: Navigation and Shopping Cart at the point where I add
this line to the Site Master.

```
   <% Html.RenderAction("Menu", "Nav"); %>
```

Running the project generates an error. CS0103: The name 'Html' does not exist in the current context

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and the project is using Framework 4.0.

Every thing to this point in the book worked fine. Now I cannot get page this. Does anyone
know how to fix this error.
These are the name spaces added to the webconfig

```
  <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="SportsStore.WebUI.HtmlHelpers"  />
   </namespaces>
```

Full Site.Master listing.

```
    <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="SportsStore.WebUI.Views.Shared.Site" %>
```

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
 <link rel="Stylesheet" href="~/Content/Site.css" />
```

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
 <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server" />
   <div id="content">
        <div id="categories">
            <% Html.RenderAction("Menu", "Nav"); %>
        </div>
   </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
  <div id="header">
    <div class="title">SPORTS STORE</div>
</div>



</div>

</form>
```

Comment: I suspect some assembly is missing.

Answer (score 3):

I see that your master inherits from `SportsStore.WebUI.Views.Shared.Site` which is a custom class. Make sure that this custom class derives from `System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage` so that the `Html` property is defined.

Comment: Look like I cannot simply replace the line "public partial class Site: System.Web.UI.MasterPage
iwth public partial class Site: System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage.
I also tried public partial class Site: System.Web.UI.MasterPage, System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage but that would not compile. Can you show me the code? Thanks.

Comment: I contacted apress and they told me where to download the code from the book. Again the book is Pro ASP.NET MVC 2 Framework, Second Edition, Updated. After downloading the code, I found I had to remove the Site.Master code behind and designer files from the project. I also had to change the site.master to inherit the System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage. Thanks Chirag for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Reolution.
I contacted apress and they told me where to download the code from the book. Again the book is Pro ASP.NET MVC 2 Framework, Second Edition, Updated. After downloading the code, I found I had to remove the Site.Master code behind and designer files from the project. I also had to change the site.master to inherit the System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage. Thanks Chirag for your time. – pary just now edit